# how to insert data in table using select statement in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two tables  Login table and  userinfo table. UserInfo table is primary key(UserId) table and login table is foreign key(UserId) table. So my problem is when i insert data in login table value of userid column should come from Userinfo table and value of other columns of log in table like username and password should be inserted directly . Is it possible in single insert statement.

i did the following but it didnt work

```
insert into login(Userid,username,password)
values(select max(userid) from userinfo,sumit,sumit123)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
insert into login(Userid,username,password)
values((select max(userid) from userinfo),'sumit','sumit123');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into login (Userid, username, password) 
select max(userid), 'sumit', 'sumit123'
from userinfo
```

[Please note: while that is syntactically correct, I probably wouldn't do it that way.]

Comment: Presumably the OP should be using `scope_identity` here rather than  `max` at all.

Comment: i was typing that as you entered...scope_identity() or the OUTPUT clause possibly...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a inner JOIN?

INSERT INTO Insurance (Name)
    SELECT Employee.Username FROM Employee
    INNER JOIN Project ON Employee.EmployeeID = Project.EmployeeID
    WHERE Project.ProjectName = 'Hardwork';

Comment: where did the project/insurance/employee table come from? or did you just post any SQL that was to hand?

Comment: Yea just grabbed a snippet I had just to show the basic construct of the statement. User didnt specify all tables/fields in question so was just improvising.